# How to enable a Button with its CanExecute method

Tags: c#, wpf, button, prism, icommand

I am developing an application in WPF using MVVM, but I am stuck with the ICommand objects.

I have a windows which contains some buttons, so, I bind them to their respective ICommand in XAML as below:

```
<Button Command="{Binding DoSomethingCommand}" Content="Do Something" />
```

Then, In my view-model class I have written the following:

```
public class MyViewModel : ObservableObject
{

    private bool isDoSomethingButtonEnabled = false;
    ....        
    public ICommand DoSomethingCommand
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }
    ....
    ....
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        DoSomethingCommand = new DelegateCommand<String>(this.OnDoSomething, this.CanDoSomething);
    }

    private void OnDoSomething(String arg)
    {

    }

    private bool CanDoSomething(String arg)
    {
        return isDoSomethingButtonEnabled;
    }
    ....
}
```

So, Since I need that my button is not enabled the first time the window opens, I set my variable `isDoSomethingButtonEnabled` to `false`. And it works, the button is disabled at the beginning, but my problem is that when I change the variable `isDoSomethingButtonEnabled` to `true` at run time my button is still disabled.

I have even done some tests after changing the variable `isDoSomethingButtonEnabled` to `true`, printing the result of `DoSomethingCommand.CanExecute()` and it shows "true"!

so, what Should I do in order to enable my button??

Thank you in advance

Comment: MVVM is a pattern, it doesn't require any specific classes like DelegateCommand. Are you using PRISM?

Comment: Yes, I am. Actually I have to use it

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There is an event called [CanExecuteChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.icommand.canexecutechanged)  on the `ICommand` interface which:

> Occurs when changes occur that affect whether or not the command
>   should execute.

With the Prism [DelegateCommand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff654132) you can raise this event with the `RaiseCanExecuteChanged` method:

```
public void SomeMethod()
{
    //do some work
    isDoSomethingButtonEnabled = true;
    DoSomethingCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
}
```

Comment: thank you for your reply. I have tried waht you just wrote but my ICommand object does not have such method, It has the event `CanExecuteChanged`, do I need to add a method to it?

Comment: You already have this method, you just need to cast back your `DoSomethingCommand` from `ICommand` to `DelegateCommand<T>`. In your sample try it with `((DelegateCommand<string>)DoSomethingCommand).RaiseCanExecuteChanged();`

Comment: Or you can change the type of `DoSomethingCommand` from `ICommand`  to
`DelegateCommand<String>`.

Comment: I am struggling with the same issue, I am wondering how this can be done with a TextBox, where the RaiseCanExecuteChanged must be called with every keystroke in the TextBox (after the TextChanged event).....

Comment: RaiseCanExecuteChanged does not work (does not enable or disable the button at run time) for me.

Comment: Are you calling RaiseCanExecuteChanged on the correct thread? There may be something more complex as to why it does not work.